# NG SERVE as production mode? Is it reliable?

Tags: angular, nginx, build

This is a silly question, building the app to production is not working out as it's giving me 404 errors as I reload any route other than /index.html, so I am able to forward the localhost server to a public server name using Nginx, so is it a bad thing to run Angular with

> ng serve

as production mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `ng serve` in production mode. (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5274#issuecomment-284719639)

Build your project using `ng build --prod`. This will generate static html, css and javascript files in the dist folder, that you can host using any http server.

Depending on your platform you could use apache, nginx or a nodejs based alternative such as express or node http-server.

The documentation on deployment of an angular app is located here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

I strongly sugges you go through it to understand what best fits your needs.